# react-native-text-detector worked fine in android but why it always returned false in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, ocr

First, I used https://github.com/jeanpan/react-native-camera-roll-picker#readme to get an image from photo library, it returned a uri: ph://11A68DD6-A651-462D-BDAB-68FB853ED141/L0/001

Then, I used https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector to get text from that image

It worked fine in android but it always returned false in iOS, and I found the following error in console log

NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

For more information, the image control can show that image correctly

Here is my source code : https://github.com/haison8x/react-native-test-ocr

Is there any problem with that URI or with application permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the sandbox policy of Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html, your app cannot read the photo in gallery directly, it will encounter the error: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002.

Here is my approach:

- Use RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS copy photo to temp file at your app documents
- Use react-native-text-detector to analyze that temp file

The full example is pushed to https://github.com/haison8x/react-native-test-ocr